# What kind of cable between Amp, Looper and Monitor

Tags: looping, cable

My Equipment:

- Nice guitar
- Kemper Profiling Amp
- Boss RC-300 Looper
- Roland Cube Monitor

---

My Setup:

[image]

---

My Question:

What kind of cable should I use on connection between Amp->Looper (2) and Looper->Monitor (3)? (Instrument Cable? Speaker Cable?)

Comment: I have to downvote this - a rare occurrence - as it shows little or no effort to research an answer. Having and being able to use equipment such as this, that knowledge really ought to have been sorted at the buying stage.

Comment: You never use a speaker cable to connect two things that both have power cords. If the Roland cube has its own power (which I’m 99% sure it does) then you do not use a speaker cable to connect it. Generally you know when you need a speaker cable. It’s only used between power amps and passive speaker cabinets.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I'd say the Roland could have AC input,(can't be certain)  whereas the other bits are most likely 9VDC in. Obviously one wouldn't use anything but shielded cable, but is there a safety issue in what you say? I've used vice versa in a desperate situation, with no apparent problems (only 150 watts).

Comment: The Kemper comes in versions with and without a power amp.   Both are mains powered.  It's a thoroughly over-specified bit of gear, with several output options!  I think the most basic one will be used here.

Answer (score 3):

Standard screened jack-to-jack cables. No need for anything fancy.  Just the very first run, from guitar to Kemper, deserves care.  The low level into high impedence of a guitar signal can be sensitive to cable capacitance.  Which is a lousy bit of electrical design, but we're stuck with it.

Answer (score 2):

The cables themselves all need to be screened - as in a central core, and wire wrapped round it. Exactly like a normal, regular guitar lead. The plugs will most likely be standard jacks, 1/4", but *could* be XLR if the equipment will take them, but for guitar eventually to normal amp., it's not necessary.

You might even get away on short runs with simple twin core, (as in speaker cable)  but it's not the best, as that tends to pick up all sorts of interference. Unless you're desperate, or short of money, do it like the pros!

Comment: British to American translation: “screened” = “shielded”; “lead” = “cable”.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - thanks - and they call it American English. Only joking!